# Hexadecimal over 7F into String in Java

Tags: java, string, hex, string-conversion

I need to append some hexadecimal characters to my string. I'm trying this:

```
content += Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(originalSize).toString(), 16));
```

And it's working, but when `originalSize` is over 127 (7F in hex) it returns me two hexadecimal values.

For example, doing this:

```
content += Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(176).toString(), 16));
```

The result is: `(content hex numbers) C0 B0`

B0 is 176 in hexadecimal, but I don't know how to remove C0. Any suggestions please? Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I want to send an string to a device via Bluetooth Low Energy. I have an string like this:

"ABCABC". In hexadecimal is `41 42 43 41 42 43`.

Now, I want to add the format of this string (because the device is waiting for it), so I add it at the end: `41 42 43 41 42 43 7E 06 02`, where:

- `7E`: beggining of the format
- `06:` number of chars
- `02`: specifical format given by manufacturer.

I have the main string and I'm adding this three hexadecimal characters by hand.

**SOLUTION:**

Based on Devon_C_Miller answer I found my own solution:

```
contentFormated = new byte[originalSize+3];

for(int i=0;i<originalSize;i++){
    contentFormated[i] = content.getBytes()[i];
}

contentFormated[originalSize] = 0x7E;
contentFormated[originalSize+1] = (byte) 0xB0;
contentFormated[originalSize+2] = 0x02;
```

Comment: "I need to append some hexadecimal characters to my string." It sounds like you're getting off to a bad start right away. What *exactly* do you mean by "hexadecimal characters"? I assume you mean you have *binary* data which represents text in a certain encoding. What encoding? How familiar are you with encodings?

Comment: @JonSkeet Let me clarify my question :)

Comment: It sounds like you want to work with binary data. Why are you using a string then? Remember that in Java, strings are Unicode, so characters don't correspond to bytes.

Comment: @FranVerona: Doing so with full code would be helpful. The *result* of appending to a string is a string, not "content hex numbers" (which could mean one of a number of things).

Comment: I edited my own question. I just need to add some hex characters at the end of an string, so I'm getting into hexadecimal, adding what I want, and return the new string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a byte array rather than a String:

```
byte[] content = {0x42, 0x43, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x7E, 0x06, 0x02};
```

Comment: The problem when I try to add sizes over 127 (i.e. 0xB0) to the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can forget about the hexadecimal notation, as the conversion is back and forth.

If you really mean the character 0xB0 (hex) or in other notation 176 decimal, you would do it as:

```
int c = 176;
content += Character.toChars(c);
```

As the string is encoded with Unicode thus might result in other bytes.
As said in the comments, if you want byte values, use byte[] or better [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), using `write(176)` and at the end `toByteArray`.

---

***Explanation***

In the ASCII range 0-127 Character.toChars give one char, represented in UTF-8 with one byte.

In the ISO-8859-* range 160-255 also one char, one byte.
In the range 128-159 there reside mostly UTF-8 control characters, like in ASCII 0-32.

But some values are used for UTF-8 multi-byte encoding.
Higher values 256-... might give one char (16bits) or several chars.

Answer (score 0):

```
hexString = String.format ("%x", 176);
```

is another option.